# The Android draw order for bitmaps, drawables and text?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a small game in android. Anything that needs to be drawn on screen extends my `VisibleObject` class, I then have a `Manager` class that i can add all my visible game objects to and each frame i tell the manager to call the draw function of everything within it.

Here's were objects are initialised and added to the manager:

```
@Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        fps = new TextDrawable(Color.BLACK, 14, 100, 40, 40);
        player = new Player();
        map = new Map();
        leftTouch = new TouchCircle(Color.GRAY);

        manager.add("fpsText", fps);
        manager.add("leftTouch", leftTouch);
        manager.add("player", player);
        manager.add("map", map);

        gameloop = new GameLoop(getHolder(), this, fps);            
        gameloop.setRunning(true);
        gameloop.start();

    }
```

Now the problem i'm having is with the draw order, if you look at the order the objects are added to the manager for reference..

- I can tell you for certain that the player is being drawn on top of
  the map! These are both drawn by drawing there respective bitmaps with `drawBitmap(..)`.
- However the fpsText and leftTouch are being drawn underneath the map! These are drawn using `drawText(..)` and `drawOval(..)` respectively.

Even though they implement different `Canvas.draw..` functions, I would expect them all to be drawn in order as I just pass the canvas object i have to my manager class and then let the manager cycle through each object passing it that canvas to draw with.

Can anyone clear up for me why bitmaps seem to be drawn on top and what the solution should be to get my fps and touch area drawn above the player and map bitmaps? I'd Appreciate it.

**EDIT:** I am using `private ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, VisibleObject> objectMap;` within my manager to store the objects and drawing like so..

```
public void draw(Canvas c){
        for (Map.Entry<String, VisibleObject> object : objectMap.entrySet()){
            synchronized(object){
                object.getValue().draw(c);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitmaps are not drawn on top of the text unless you draw Bitmap after you drawn text  (and position overlaps).

You haven't disclose onDraw method so I can't be sure, but I suspect that you are not calling drawing methods in right order.
How does you manager stores the values added to it? Maybe you use Map implementation that doesn't maintain order of elements added (most implementations don't, [LinkedHashmap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) does).

Comment: Ah that's very interesting! i've edited my question with a bit more of my code.. but i am using  ConcurrentSkipListMap and i've just read the documentation again and it says "The map is sorted according to the natural ordering of its keys" So i guess that means alphabetically, doh! :p What do you this the most suitable storage container would be for this purpose? Thank you very much for helping

Comment: Yes, it means alphabetically, so NOT in order that you added elements. LinkedHasmap would be more suitable if you really need Map, but from the code you disclosed I don't see need for Map, you could use List  implementation like ArrayList.